# What's the difference between using and not using inline integration in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to make it clear the difference between using inline integration and not using inline integration during simulation in Dymola.
Here is the basic procedure of the DASSL algorithm:
[image]

I find the following summary about the inline integration technique:

> To summarise, inline integration harnesses the symbolic manipulation of Dymola to **insert discretization expressions**, representing the numerical integration algorithms, into the differential-algebraic equation (DAE) model to be solved. In effect, the inserted discretization expressions (representing the numerical integration algorithms) are **solved “inline” with the model**, rising to the name of the technique. The upshot is a DAE which is easier to solve numerically, thus leading to a shorter solve time.

1. as to the part of `insert discretization expression into DAE model to be solved`, I think DASSL does the same thing, as shown in the above screenshot, DASSL would insert the expression of `y=h*der(y)+old(y)` into the original DAE.
2. but what does it mean by `inserted discretization expressions are solved inline with the model`?  In the DASSL algorithm, I just use Newton Method to solve the nonlinear equations of `f(y-old(y)/h,y,t)=0`, it seems natural. So what would happen if I use the inline integration method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no inline DASSL in Dymola.
For non-inline explicit Euler the C-code contain (well, with different variable names):

```
der(y)=f(y)
```

(and there is some integration code that computes `y(t+h)=y(t)+h*der(y)` ).
For inline explicit Euler the the C-code contain:

```
y(t+h)=y(t)+h*f(y)
```

The main benefits are:

- For implicit methods where each system of equation can be solved separately.
- It can be used (as an FMU/S-function) in other tools that don't themselves support the integration method.